# Simplify $\frac {n ^ 3 - 3n + (n ^ 2 - 1) \sqrt {n ^ 2 - 4} - 2}{n ^ 3 - 3n + (n ^ 2 - 1) \sqrt {n ^ 2 - 4} + 2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving a problem and got to this expression. Can I simplify it?

$$\frac {n ^ 3 - 3n + (n ^ 2 - 1) \sqrt {n ^ 2 - 4} - 2}{n ^ 3 - 3n + (n ^ 2 - 1) \sqrt {n ^ 2 - 4} + 2}, for \ every \ natural \ number \ n \ge 2.$$

Comment: Yes, you can. Show your attempts.

Comment: Identify to $\dfrac{a-b}{a+b}=\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{(a+b)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is equal to
$$\frac{(n+1)\sqrt{n^2-4}}{n^2+n-2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To get rid of the radical, use $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$
In your case, for the denominator, $a=n^3-3n+2$ and $b=(n^2-1)\sqrt{n^2-4}$. Multiply both numerator and denominator by $a-b$